# Marshal Array of Strings from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, string, marshalling

I'm using the Microsoft Docs example on Marshaling strings. The code doesn't crash, but not does return the expected strings in C#. The strings are unmodified when the native code is called, so I'm wondering if this example might be outdated?

If this example doesn't work for someone else is there another way of Marshaling C++ array of strings to C#?

**C++ example here:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/as6wyhwt(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

```
PINVOKELIB_API int TestArrayOfStrings( char* ppStrArray[], int count )
{
    int result = 0;
    STRSAFE_LPSTR temp;
    size_t len;
    const size_t alloc_size = sizeof(char) * 10;

    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    {
        len = 0;
        StringCchLengthA( ppStrArray[i], STRSAFE_MAX_CCH, &len );
        result += len;

        temp = (STRSAFE_LPSTR)CoTaskMemAlloc( alloc_size );
        StringCchCopyA( temp, alloc_size, (STRSAFE_LPCSTR)"123456789" );

       // CoTaskMemFree must be used instead of delete to free memory.

       CoTaskMemFree( ppStrArray[i] );
       ppStrArray[i] = (char *) temp;
   }

   return result;
}
```

**C# corresponding example here:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-different-types-of-arrays

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
[DllImport("..\\LIB\\PinvokeLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern int TestArrayOfstrings(
        [In, Out] string[] stringArray, int size);
}
// string array ByVal 
    string[] strArray = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nstring array before call:");
    foreach (string s in strArray)
    {
        Console.Write(" " + s);
    }
int lenSum = NativeMethods.TestArrayOfstrings(strArray, strArray.Length);
Console.WriteLine("\nSum of string lengths:" + lenSum);
Console.WriteLine("\nstring array after call:");
foreach (string s in strArray)
{
   Console.Write(" " + s);
}
```

Comment: I think you should glance at C# code on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-different-types-of-arrays

Comment: @snr That is exactly the code the OP is quoting in the question.

Comment: When I tried to run the code I got the following exception: `System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'TestArrayOfstrings'` Then I realized that there was a typo: in the C++ code the 'S' in `TestArrayOfStrings` is capital case and in the C# code it's lower case. Once I fixed the C# code it worked.

Comment: I've personally found it way simpler to write a `c++/cli` layer instead of using pinvoke.